# Do God children become God also?

Tags: gods

Do gods also have children and family tree? Do those children and relatives also have powers from god?

If yes is then the total number of normal humans less than number of gods in Hinduism?

What kind of work do these children and grandchildren of the gods have to perform in their daily life ?

Comment: the only two prominent cases are Ganesa and Kartikeya.  It is rare for Gods to have immortals as offspring.

Comment: "If yes then, Are normal humans are less than number of gods population in Hinduism?" It depends on your definition of 33 crore. If it is million then there are more devtas the humans but if you mean types then therr are far less.

Comment: "What all work do this god children and grandchildren of god have" I suggest you improve your English grammar skills.

Comment: @Wikash_ fine now ?edited

Comment: No. I will help.

Comment: Does that mean that it's not possible to have children for those who have attained turiya?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Due to the curse of goddess parvathi,  gods never give birth to the kids.

According to the story,  lord **siva and parvathi**  were in devine dance(romance),  one day  indra and all other gods known this, they had got fear of thought like 'siva and parvathi' very powerful sakthi, if they given birth to any  child,  he will be more powerful than us'.  So they had devised a plan and was going ask to lord siva as a desire.

**Lord siva** is kind person, greatest god and father of whole universe.  he always come down for their sons(baktas)

So all gods approached to lord siva, when lord siva were in alone. All gods had asked their desire 'dont give birth' in respected manner.  Lord siva known every thing,  that illeagal desire would went to bad. Lord siva warned the gods, but they did not come down on that desire. Finally maha dev fullfilled their desire.

After some time goddess parvathi known this illegal desire gods got fullfilled by lord siva.  Goddess parvathi could not tolarate,  got angred,  and fire upon gods. Due to which
'She g[iven curse](https://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga36/bala_36_frame.htm) to whole gods would never give birth to their kids'. Thats its gods stopped at 33 million.

> अद्य प्रभृति युष्माकमप्रजाः सन्तु पत्नयः || १-३६-२२ एवमुक्त्वा
>   सुरान्सर्वान् शशाप पृथिवीमपि |
>
> " 'And from now onwards you wives shall remain infertile...' and on
>   saying this way to all of the gods she also gave a curse to the earth.

**Goddess parvathi** is also lady(sthri in respect),  all woman lifes fullfilled when they given birth.

But she is mother of whole universe,  adi para sakthi, she also knows every thing.

**----Chaganti koteswara rao garu----**

Comment: Though Chaganti koteswara rao garu is known for his highly motivating spiritual lectures in Telugu, you should quote references from scriptures like Ramayana or Mahabharata or Puranas, etc, in your answer.  Otherwise your answer is liable to be rejected.  I had supplemented required reference for this answer.  Next time onwards, please quote references.

Comment: Does that mean that it's not possible to have children for those who have attained turiya?

Comment: what is the turiya?  means

Comment: Indra has a son named Jayanta and daughter named Jayanti - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayanta